# How to delete a subkey on Linux in GnuPG?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, encryption, gnupg, gpg-agent

I would like to delete an OpenPGP subkey of mine on Linux (L)Ubuntu 16.04 in GnuPG. It's a kind of "blank" useless key (see below key `33333333`). I have not uploaded it to key servers, so  I think it's ok to delete without revoking it.

```
gpg2 --edit-key me@example.com

sec  rsa4096/11111111
     created: 2016-12-12  expires: 2017-12-12  usage: SC  
     confiance : ultime        validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa4096/22222222
     created: 2016-12-12  expires: 2017-12-12  usage: E   
ssb  rsa4096/33333333
     created: 2016-12-12  expires: never       usage:     
ssb  rsa4096/44444444
     créé : 2016-12-12  expires: 2017-12-12  usage: S   
[  ultimate ] (1). me <me@example.com>
```

I tried "gpg> delkey 33333333", but I had this message :

```
You must select at least one key.
(Use the 'key' command.)
```

then `gpg> key 33333333`, and I had this result (same result as `list` command):

```
sec  rsa4096/11111111
     created: 2016-12-12  expires: 2017-12-12  usage: SC  
     confiance : ultime        validity: ultimate
ssb  rsa4096/22222222
     created: 2016-12-12  expires: 2017-12-12  usage: E   
ssb  rsa4096/33333333
     created: 2016-12-12  expires: never       usage:     
ssb  rsa4096/44444444
     créé : 2016-12-12  expires: 2017-12-12  usage: S   
[  ultimate ] (1). me <me@example.com>
```

What should I do next?

Comment: On the Linux command line (and in general), you can get English language outpuut for pretty much all applications by prefixing `LANG=C`, eg. `LANG=C gpg2 --edit-key ...`. Alternatively, "switch" a shell to English language by running `export LANG=C`.

Comment: Small caution to anyone deleting a subkey, if you delete even a _public_ subkey it may mean that the related private subkey is no longer available to decrypt. I was able to fix it easily - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262703/deleted-a-subkey-and-can-now-no-longer-decrypt/ not sure if is always like that though.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

GnuPG's interactive `--edit-key` menu works differently. You do not select a subkey by `key [subkey-id]`, but by `key [key-index]`, in your case this would be `key 2` (the second subkey from the top, the primary key doesn't count).

After doing so, the line

```
ssb  rsa4096/33333333
```

will change to

```
ssb* rsa4096/33333333
```

with an asterisk indicating the key being selected. After selecting one or more keys, run `delkey` to delete the selected subkeys. Don't forget to `save`!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had not seen the asterisk thing before. Thank you !
PS : key-index number was 2, not 3 (I could not select the first "sec" key).

Comment: You're right, I should have only counted the subkeys. If this answered your question, consider selecting the checkmark on the left (also have a look at the [FAQ]).

Comment: wow that was unintuitive. I kept selecting by key-id.